# How to edit color of button

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

I have a edit form of a task list, i am  using the content type "Workflow Task (Sharepoint 2013)", it has 2 buttons, one for **Approve** and other for **Deny**.

I need to change the color of the Approve and Deny buttons, i have tried with Sharepoint Designer (Doesn't allow me to edit the form, even if I have full control permissions) and i have tried with Content Editor as well using below code inside a script tag:

```
  function changeColors () {
    documento.getElementById("Status_c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76_$DropDownChoice_Aprobado").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  
  document.onload= changeColors();
```

But, it doesn't work until I fire the event in the developer console.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create new txt file and add this code (put your color code)

```
<style>
#Status_c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76_\$DropDownChoice_Approved {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
#Status_c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76_\$DropDownChoice_Rejected {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

2.Save file as for ex buttonColor.txt

3.Upload file to SiteAssets (site/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx)

4.Add content editor webpart on editform.aspx (edit page add webpart).

Edit content webpart properties > link txt file from siteassets to webpart `/SiteAssets/buttonColor.txt`